# Get Netatmo data of multiple stations in R or python

Tags: python, r, oauth, httr

I am looking to compare Netatmo temperature data to the local's government data.
Is there a way to download Netatmo data for multiple stations using R or python or can only the station owner download their data?

Answer (score -1):

If you are only interested in outdoor data, you can use the public API to retrieve a list of stations in the area that interests you:

https://dev.netatmo.com/resources/technical/reference/weatherapi/getpublicdata

If you need some historic, use that method:

https://dev.netatmo.com/resources/technical/reference/common/getmeasure

Comment: Please edit relevant part of your links into your answer, for example by quoting those parts.